# How to use HtmlAgilityPack to get this two content?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Html code:

```
<div>
    <div>Name</div>
    Date
</div>
```

How to use HtmlAgilityPack to get the `Name` and `Date` values?

Comment: I tried `InnerText` on the outer div, but it got `NameDate`

Answer (score 1):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode div in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//div"])
 {
    string parent = div.InnerText; //this will give you Name
    foreach (HtmlNode child in div.ChildNodes)
    {
     string childDiv = child.InnerText; //this will give you the child
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the `Value` property. I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack.1.4.5\Net45\HtmlAgilityack.dll`

Comment: There is no "Value" property on an HtmlNode. You can use InnerText or InnerHtml.

Comment: @Freewind my apologies .Value is a property on attribute, Kvein is correct please use InnerText

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<div><div>Name</div>Date</div>");
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode
    .DescendantNodes()
    .Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text);
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    var value = node.InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard-coded:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<div><div>Name</div>Date</div>");
                Console.WriteLine(((HtmlTextNode)doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0]).Text);
Console.WriteLine(((HtmlTextNode)doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes[1]).Text);
```

If what you're looking for, is all the text nodes (as in Kevin Babcock's answer!). You have to remember that text in Xml (and with HtmlAgility) are nodes.